# Get JS object reference by multiple-level string value

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve such thing through JavaScript so I'm asking for help here.

I have a string:

```
var value = 'level1.level2.level3';
```

And I have an object:

```
var object = {
    level1 : {
        level2 : {
            level3 : 0
        },
    },
}
```

Is it possible to get a reference to that object using string value, not just value of specific object key. Using a traverse function but a reference so it could be possible to operate with it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rhbh2g9/)

I've checked and I'm sure this is NOT a duplicate question since in a duplicate version result of parsing function will be **object key value**, **not the object key itself**.

Comment: I'm afraid, you will have to write it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One liner:

```
[ob].concat(value.split('.')).reduce(function(a, b) { return a[b] })
```

Sample:

```js
Object.prototype.getValue = function(path) {
    return [this].concat(path.split('.')).reduce(function(a, b) { return a[b] });
}

// usage:

alert((
{
    level1 : {
        level2 : {
           level3 : 0
        },
    },
}).getValue('level1.level2.level3'));
```

You cannot change the value of `0` in this way because it will be not an object reference

You need to get `level1.level2` object and change its `level3` field if you want to affect your original object

```
ob.getValue('level1.level2').level3 = 25;
```

- that's how javascript work

However, its possible to write a method to set its value

```js
Object.prototype.setValue = function(path, value) {
    var last = (path = path.split('.')).splice(-1);
    [this].concat(path).reduce(function(a, b) { return a[b] })[last] = value;
}

var ob = {
  level1 : {
     level2 : {
       level3 : 0
     }
  }
};

ob.setValue('level1.level2.level3', 25);

alert(ob.level1.level2.level3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue(object, path) {
    var array = path.split('.');
    var current = object;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        current = current[array[i]];
    }
    return current;
}
```

Use example `var x = getValue(object, value);`

Answer (score 0):

Although I hate using `eval`, you can try it if you absolutly sure about `value`:

```js
var object = {
  level1 : {
     level2 : {
       level3 : 'text'
     }
  }
};

var value = 'level1.level2.level3';

$('.result').text(eval('object.' + value));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='result'></div>
```

Comment: it works, but the performance of `eval` is very bad!